# What does it mean for spectral graph representation methods to be limited to a single graph structure?

Tags: graph-neural-network

I'm trying to get deeper into the topic of graph neural networks. While reading [this paper](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/view/11782) recently, I came across a statement that confused me. The authors state that spectral methods are limited to a "single graph structure", while spatial methods are not.

> One limitation of the above [referring to [2](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2016/hash/04df4d434d481c5bb723be1b6df1ee65-Abstract.html)] spectral formulations is that they rely on
> the fixed spectrum of the graph Laplacian, and thus are suitable only
> for graphs with a single structure (and varying signals on vertices).
> Spatial formulations, on the contrary, are not restricted to a fixed
> graph structure.

Could somebody explain to me what that means? What exactly is this limitation about? And are GCNs (as an instance of spectral graph convolutions (?)) affected by this?

Comment: I would interpret this argument to be directly targeting the "spectral filters as Chebyshev polynomials of eigenvalues" papers. I believe what they mean, is that these methods only work for one particular graph structure always. So the nodes and edges (but not their features) cannot vary. The GCN, however, can work for graph with different sizes.